# Open dialog box won't show files in libraries, but explorer will

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-libraries

I have the weirdest problem when trying to open or save files. When I try to get to "My Documents" through the "Libraries" side link it won't show any of my files. It will show them if I go around from the C:// drive into the user files though. I thought it was because I didn't have the right location defined for the "Libraries" shortcut, but when I use "Explorer" to open my "Libraries" it shows all the files. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try right-clicking Libraries and Restoring Default Libraries.

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: windows 7 home premium

Comment: @Alex do you have remove shortcut arrow icon from the desktop icons?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a not too uncommon issue. I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer as to why it happens, or what specifically you can do to fix it.

In most cases though, the problem seems to fix itself if you go into properties for the library in question and click "Restore Defaults". Click OK, and then, if you had any custom folders included, just go back in and include them again.

Good luck!

Comment: Ya I tries that. It didn't do anything...